# Why aren't all my posts retrieving?

Tags: pagination

I am trying to create a small custom snippet of code to generate a query of posts on my website. I use the plugin Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to tag the country of origin on to posts on the website. I am now trying to add a snippet of code to each countries information page so that I get a query of all the results. Here is my example page https://rose.directory/topics/regional-rose-culture/european-culture-history-of-roses/france-history-culture-of-the-rose/ and my example code is below. Looking forward to your feedback, thank you kindly.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'country_of_origin',
    'meta_value'    => 'France',
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_field('event_thumbnail'); ?>" />
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

PS I would love to be able to have a more beautiful looking query loop but honestly I don't know how to make it look more like other pages on my website. Any styling advice appreciated as well. Thanks again for taking the time to read!

Comment: Try replacing numberposts with posts_per_page

Comment: @birgire - it didn't seem to make any difference. I wrote it like this;

'posts_per_page'   => '50',

but there is no noticeable change at;

https://rose.directory/topics/regional-rose-culture/european-culture-history-of-roses/france-history-culture-of-the-rose/

Comment: oops I set it to 1000 and it works great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it solved the issue, I will add it as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `numberposts` argument is not supported by `WP_Query`, the solution to the above question was to use instead `posts_per_page.`

Answer (score 0):

Try code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'country_of_origin',
            'value'   => 'France',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
else:
    echo 'No posts found.';
endif;
```